# Cannot upload image using filepath in MS-Azure Blob Storage

Tags: php, html, azure

I am developing a web application using Microsoft Azure services. I am following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-php?tabs=linux) link to upload an image to my blob storage, but there are a few bits and pieces missing in the document that leads to certain issues. For instance, how do we define the variable $fileToUpload and how will it relate to the variable $myfile? Also, if we want to choose to upload a file from our system when the application is running, in which of the two variables should we have the absolute file path to my image? The code I have written till now to upload an image is as follows:

```php
function imageupload(string $current_user){
    $pt_id = $_POST['patientid'];
    if (strcmp($pt_id,"")==0){
        echo "Select PatientID to continue";
    }else{
        $accountexists = load($current_user, $pt_id);
        if ($accountexists == 0){
            $error = "Patient Id does not exist";
            echo $error;
        }else{
            $img_path = $_POST['uploadI'];
            if (strcmp($img_path, "")==0){
                 echo "Enter valid image path <br />";
            }
            else{
                require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
                $connectionString = '****';
                // Create blob client.
                $blobClient = BlobRestProxy::createBlobService($connectionString);

                # Create the BlobService that represents the Blob service for the storage account

                $containerName = $current_user;

                $num = rand(10,10000);
                $num2 = (string) $num;
                $fileToUpload = $pt_id."_".$num2;

                # Upload file as a block blob
                echo "Uploading image: ".PHP_EOL;
                echo $img_path;
                echo "<br />";


                $content = fopen($img_path, "r");

                //Upload blob
                $blobClient->createBlockBlob($containerName, $fileToUpload, $content);
                echo "Image uploaded successfully! <br />";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this code, I am storing my path to the image in the variable $img_path. And this is the code I am using for displaying the image later:

```php
// Gets all the images from the hospital's container and filters out the images corresponding to a particular patient. 
// For the patient, the image would be saved on cloud with name as: <patientid>_<some random number>
// Eg- patient id= pt1 , so image name could be- pt1_3682
function uploadedimage(string $current_user, string $HospitalId, string $PatientId){
  $containerName = $HospitalId;
  $url = "";
  try{
      // Get blob.
      require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
      // use MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Common\ServicesBuilder;
      $connectionString = '****';

      $blobClient = BlobRestProxy::createBlobService($connectionString);
      $blob_list = $blobClient->listBlobs($containerName);
      $blobs = $blob_list->getBlobs();
      $strlen = strlen($PatientId);
      $array_user = array();
      // echo "These are the blobs present in the container: ";
      foreach($blobs as $blob)
      {
          $name =  $blob->getName();
          $namesub = substr($name,0, $strlen);
          if (strcmp($namesub, $PatientId) == 0){
              array_push($array_user, $blob);
          }
      }
  }
  catch(ServiceException $e){
    $code = $e->getCode();
    $error_message = $e->getMessage();
    echo $code.": ".$error_message."<br />";
  }

  $url = "";
  try    {
      foreach($array_user as $blob)
      {
          $name =  $blob->getName();
          $url = $blob->getUrl();
          echo "<img src=\"".$url."\" alt=\"image post\"></br></br>";

      }

  }
  catch(ServiceException $e){
      $code = $e->getCode();
      $error_message = $e->getMessage();
      echo $code.": ".$error_message."<br />";
  }
}
```

But I cannot seem to view my image in the html  that I have specified. All I get is the default text "image post". Thus I have concluded there is something I am missing in my code due to which the images are not being uploaded but I can't seem to figure that out from the azure tutorial.

Edit: I checked my blob properties and they are all of 0 size, which means that they are not being uploaded properly. Also I realised that there are some images that were pushed to the cloud along with my code in my git folder. So if there is a particular image by the name *abc.png* already existing in the same directory as my code on Azure and while uploading this image from my web application, if in the path text box I specify only *abc.png*, that image gets uploaded in my container in it's correct size, but if that same image is present on my desktop and if I specify the complete filepath of my local system for this image (or some other image not present in the git directory existing on azure) as *C:/Desktop/abc.png*, it gets uploaded as only 0 bytes image (which is essentially not being uploaded properly). What can be the issues if it is not able to take images from my system and can only take the images already existing in it's git directory?

Comment: `But I cannot seem to view my image in the html that I have specified. All I get is the default text "image post".` - 2 things you could check for: 1) Images are uploaded properly. You could check it using Microsoft's Storage Explorer or even Azure Portal. and 2) Check container's ACL. It should not be Private. This again you can check using Storage Explorer or Portal.

Comment: Assuming the upload worked successfully, and assuming the url looks well-formed, then I suspect @GauravMantri nailed your problem, in that your blobs are (by default) private. You cannot access a private blob by its direct URI without a SAS (shared access signature) providing temporary public access. There are many questions & answers on this site addressing details of SAS, along with a lot of documentation around it on Microsoft's doc pages.

Comment: I checked my Public Access Level of each Blob and all of them are set to 'Container (anonymous read access for container and bolbs)'.

Comment: Can you share the actual URL for a blob?

Comment: This is the actual URL of one of my blobs. https://csgca0fe5001639x4957x908.blob.core.windows.net/aiims

Comment: This is the URL of the blob container and not the blob in that container. I took the liberty of enumerating blobs in that container in your storage account and found a blob by the name `012345_2017`. The blob URL for this would be `https://csgca0fe5001639x4957x908.blob.core.windows.net/aiims/012345_2017`. You would need to use that. HTH.

Comment: @GauravMantri I checked and realised that all the images I am trying to upload from my system by specifying the filepath goes as 0 bytes, while there are certain images that were pushed in the same git directory as my code on azure, only they could be uploaded in their correct sizes by just mentioning their names (and no filepath). I have explained the details in my edit above. Basically this code is unable to upload images correctly from a given filepath.